# Can the stand alone VMware vCenter converter run locally and save to a windows file share on another machine

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-server

I need to backup a server before it is wiped for a new instalation of Windows 2008. We will be implementing vmware in the near future, so I thought I would just p2v the server. I have a share created on another server (MachineB\SomeShare). Can I run the client for VMware vCenter Converter Standalone from MachineA (the one I want to backup), and point the destination system to MachineB\SomeShare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem as long as you map the remote share as a local network drive. I have done this from a vcenter server onto a mapped drive from a fileserver a few times. Just prepare for the p2v conversion to take quite some time.

Comment: yikes.. 200gb hd space, how long should I expect? Thx for confirmation

Comment: It all depends on your network throughput and the write speed of the server/machine that you're saving the .vmdk to. I've seen this type of process take over a day.

Comment: Is there a better option? I had it in my head there was some kind of boot up p2v process before windows even loaded. I obviously have zero experience with this, so welcome any suggestions